# I can't delete my clone node when I click the delete botton which had been binded the click event

Tags: jquery

The first snippet of my codes, which is in the file named sys_Param.aspx:

```
<div id="div_water" style="display: none" align="center">  
<table width="100%" border="0" id="printTbl" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="table">
    <tr class="TR_BG_list" id="printsizescroll" style="display:none">
        <td align="right" class="list_link" style="width: 214px">
        Resize the pictrue：
        </td>
        <td align="left" class="list_link">
            Description:
        <asp:TextBox ID="PrintSizeDec" runat="server" CssClass="form"  style="width: 106px"/>
         width|height:
        <asp:TextBox ID="PrintSmallSize" runat="server" CssClass="form"  style="width: 50px"/>
&nbsp;
        <label>
             <input type="button" name="PintSizeAddClick" value="Add" class="form" id="ButtonAdd" style="width: 44px" onclick="createInputTexts(this)" />
        </label>
       <span class="helpstyle" style="cursor: help;" title="Click to get some help" onclick="Help('H_WaterParam_0008',this)">Help</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="TR_BG_list">
<td align="center" colspan="2" class="list_link">
    <label>
    <input type="submit" name="Savewater" value=" Submit " class="form" id="Savewater" runat="server" onserverclick="Savewater_ServerClick" />
    </label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label>
    <input type="reset" name="Clearwater" value=" Reset " class="form" id="Clearwater" runat="server" />
    </label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Another part: the event handler :

```
function createInputTexts() {

    var trOrigin = $("#printsizescroll");
    var trClone = trOrigin.clone(true);
    var target = $("#printTbl tr:last-child").prev();

    trClone.find(":button").val("delete");
    $('#printTbl').on('click', 'input[type="button"][value="delete"]', function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
    });   
    trClone.css('display', '');
    // Here you can also set new ID.
    target.after(trClone);
}
```

The question is: when I click the delete button,it doesn't delete the new clone row which was created by jQuery dynamicly.I was so confused,cause I have bind the click event to every delete button. 
I need some help, thanks a millious.

Comment: please create a demo on [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with the outputted markup, and be more specific, what doesn't work?

Comment: I have try to add some words to make my question much more specific,is that ok?

Comment: You have onclick event already specified for your button which becomes delete button. You have to unbind click event from it and add new click event which will handle deletion

Comment: var trClone = trOrigin.clone(true); this is to make a new row and the button was use to delete the new row when needed. here is the link of jsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/qV4jG/3/

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();` grandparents

Comment: I have updated your fiddle for better debugging, here: http://jsfiddle.net/qV4jG/15/

Comment: I have removed the asp.net tag, it's just a jquery issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look if this is the effect you want: http://jsfiddle.net/qV4jG/16/

The cloned buttons still have the `onclick` attribute, so I removed them before binding a click event as seen in this part:

```
  trClone.addClass("deleteBtn"+i).find(":button").val("delete").removeAttr('onclick').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
  });
```

Comment: Yes! That is what I want.  But when I paste your code in my project, it still can't work: the delete button can't delete that new created row. Does it have something to do with the using of TextBox instead of the input tag in my .aspx page?

Comment: Make sure there are no javascript errors. You can remove the `i` in my example code if there are JS errors, like so: `trClone.addClass("deleteBtn")`. As long as you are using the same input button. Are you using an input button?

Comment: I have removed the i and test it in Firefox,everything is good. It is so wired that it can work perfectly in Firefox but still can't work in IE9 . I don't why

Comment: The code you given me can work in both IE9 and Firefox ,but once apply in my wen-project it can only work in Firefox , IE9 can not